# Restkit: including field from request into object mapping

Tags: core-data, restkit, rkobjectmapping

I am making rest call as this

```
GET /entities?parent=123
[
    {id:1, name:"name 1"},
    {id:2, name:"name 2"}
]
```

My entity defination have following fields

```
id
name
parent
```

The problem is that parent field is not coming in the response, It is in the request. How can I save parent field from request to coredata?

I have tried to search these things with no luck.

- I have tried looking for some transformers which could transform response before being processed by restkit but could not find anything.
- I have seen Metadata Mapping in RKObjectRequestOperation but could not figure out if/how this can be used.

thanks

EDIT

Answer provided below works only if that is used with object manager. So the following works

```
RKDynamicMapping *learningObjectMapping = [MTAbstractLearningObject map];//this contains metadata mapping for @metadata.routing.parameters.entityId
RKResponseDescriptor* learningObjRd = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:learningObjectMapping 
    method:RKRequestMethodGET pathPattern:@"entity/:entityId" keyPath:@"objects" 
    statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
[self.objectManager addResponseDescriptor:learningObjRd];
[self.objectManager.router.routeSet addRoute:[RKRoute routeWithName:@"learningObjects" pathPattern:@"entity/:id" method:RKRequestMethodGET]];
```

If object manager is constructed as shown above, and requests are made as shown below.

```
[self.objectManager getObjectsAtPathForRouteNamed:@"learningObjects" object:entity parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    NSLog(@"API: Success got learning objects");
}failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"API: Failed to get learning objects");
}];
```

Then it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use metadata, it includes a dictionary of query parameters that you can access. Your mapping will contain

```
@"@metadata.query.parameters.parent": @"parent"
```

Comment: you mean i can use this in RKEntityMapping? one more thing. In my case parameter is not in query string but part of url like /entites/parent/123

Comment: I was looking for concept about this. Got good pointers from this answer to explore further. Trying to find documentation about metadata mapping. got http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/RestKit/0.24.1/Classes/RKMappingOperation.html Thanks for the answer.

Comment: if you're using path components instead then you should be looking into `RKRoute`

Comment: Let me dig more into that. then I will update answer and accept it. Thanks